# Original UITableView reloads under searchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two data sources for my UITableView and my SearchDisplayController's table view.  I switch back and forth between the arrays based on a self.isSearching property.  This seems to work well, but when I use the back button from a detail view which was pushed from a search result cell tap, the default table view seems to re-load under the search result table view, which causes an out of bounds error on the array (because there are more results in the default table than the search results table).

Why is this table reloading at all?  I'm explicitly reloading the search table when viewWillAppear comes back.

This seems like a bug to me, I would imagine only the focused search result table should be reloaded if anything?  How can I return a 0 rows result from numberOfRowsInSection, if I need it for search results numbers?

Here's my methods and logs.

```
- (NSMutableArray*)cachePointer
{
    if (self.isSearching){
        return self.searchTitles;
    }else{
        return self.titles;
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.isSearching) {
        [self.searchResultsController.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %ld", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [self.cachePointer count]);
    return [self.cachePointer count];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"%@, tableView: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), tableView);
    NLSTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TitleCellIdentifier"];

    NSInteger rowAtIndex = 0;
    if (![self.cachePointer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]){
        NSLog(@"[self.cachePointer objectAtIndex:%ld = nil", indexPath.row);
        if (self.isSearching) {
            [self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self.searchController];
        } else {
            [self primeTitleCache];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"[self.cachePointer objectAtIndex:%ld = %ld", indexPath.row, [[self.cachePointer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue]);
        rowAtIndex = [[self.cachePointer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];
    }

    if (!cell) {
        NSLog(@"no cell to re-use.  self.isSearching = %d", self.isSearching);
        cell = [[NLSTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:@"TitleCellIdentifier"
                andId:rowAtIndex];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"re-using cell at indexPath %ld, pulling %ld", indexPath.row, rowAtIndex);
        [cell updateCellWithId:rowAtIndex];
    }


    return cell;
}

2015-07-11 23:59:02.850 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] viewWillAppear:
2015-07-11 23:59:02.851 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] cancelAllOperations
2015-07-11 23:59:02.852 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: 1
2015-07-11 23:59:02.855 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, tableView: <UITableView: 0x7f984d847a00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f984bd97e40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f984bf7dfc0>; contentOffset: {0, -108}; contentSize: {320, 148}>
2015-07-11 23:59:02.856 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] [self.cachePointer objectAtIndex:0 = 65398
2015-07-11 23:59:02.856 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] re-using cell at indexPath 0, pulling 65398
2015-07-11 23:59:02.856 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] updateCellWithId: 65398
2015-07-11 23:59:02.856 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] cancelAllOperations
2015-07-11 23:59:02.856 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] startQueryWithId: 65398
2015-07-11 23:59:02.857 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] initWithInvocation:andDelegate: <NSInvocation: 0x7f984f4773d0>
2015-07-11 23:59:02.857 Colleen's EMA[8080:294381] NLSTMQuery main
2015-07-11 23:59:02.857 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] initWithInvocation:andDelegate: <NSInvocation: 0x7f984f562f00>
2015-07-11 23:59:02.857 Colleen's EMA[8080:294381] SQLAPI getTitleModelForSQL:
2015-07-11 23:59:02.864 Colleen's EMA[8080:294382] NLSJournalQuery main
2015-07-11 23:59:02.864 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] startDescriptorQuery: 65398
2015-07-11 23:59:02.865 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] initWithInvocation:andDelegate: <NSInvocation: 0x7f984eac6990>
2015-07-11 23:59:02.865 Colleen's EMA[8080:294530] NLSDescriptorArrayQuery main
2015-07-11 23:59:02.866 Colleen's EMA[8080:294530] getMeshDescriptorsForId:
2015-07-11 23:59:02.868 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895]
```

Here's where you can see the cellForRowAtIndexPath call made to the underlying tableView...

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, tableView: <UITableView: 0x7f984d825000; frame = (0 20; 320 1018); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f984bd145b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f984bf7d050>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 20995512}>
    2015-07-11 23:59:02.884 Colleen's EMA[8080:293895] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
    *** First throw call stack
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that `objectAtIndex:` returns nil if the index is out of bounds:

```
if (![self.cachePointer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
{
    // index out of bounds, in fact this will never run
}
```

In fact, this won't return nil, instead an exception is raised if the index is out of bounds. The proper way to check would be:

```
if (indexPath.row >= self.cachePointer.count)
{
    // index out of bounds
}
```